# What are narrowed generics function for in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

let's suppose we have this interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    content: string;
}
```

used by these three functions:

```
function fn1<T>(arg: T): void {
    let local = arg;
    console.log(local.content);
}

function fn2<T extends MyInterface>(arg: T): void {
    let local = arg;
    console.log(local.content);
}

function fn3(arg: MyInterface): void {
    let local = arg;
    console.log(local.content);
}
```

(Here on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5BAex3AC5kBnMKUAcwG5SBfU0mAK4gEYYDWQwQARgA8AFQB8ACjhQ2DOQEoGANyrAAJoVIVkAGwhhzVBHDPIAvMlWcTFaiEZULAOjNU2JX9bMx8PSHBNLhJeEn4hETEQCRAAJnlkCAAPCINGNCwcWEQIZRcNbWQ9Q2MyCgsrYLtHZzVo0w8vX39AptDwiEjo2PjhUXFJAGYVNQYMbEhipErqo2I68gbrEJaXdvcaLog-AKCbOzCaCLAonj4SSSklAkorwbAGAHIpT%20RuW4eaWer1oH2Qn1Sv3%200SmwIG9HBkyhUSAA))

The first one correctly gives an error accessing `local.content`: "Property 'content' does not exist on type 'T'".
So in `fn2` I decide to narrow the generics type with `extends MyInterface` to be sure that `local.content` exists. But what about `fn3`? What's the difference beetween `fn2` and `fn3`?
To me it's clear the usage of generics without constraints, while I don't understand why I should use narrowed generics even with union types:

```
function fn4<T extends MyInterface | MyInterface2>(arg: T): void {
    let local = arg;
    console.log(local.content);
}
```

vs.

```
function fn5(arg: MyInterface | MyInterface2): void {
    let local = arg;
    console.log(local.content);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is indeed no point to use generics for non-generic code. `fn5` and `fn3` are alright. It would have been difference if you needed to `return arg;` in both cases.

Comment: @zerkms is correct. Note that the correct term is "constrain" not "narrow". The latter refers to a different aspect of the type system.